# Delete calls memset?

Tags: c++, memset, delete-operator

Why in call stack after `delete this;` the following function is being called?

```
msvcr110d.dll!_VEC_memset(void * dst, int val, int len)
```

Please consider that `operator delete` is not overloaded.

Comment: Are you in debug mode or release mode?

Comment: Is that a debug build? If so, it's to fill the dead memory with a known bit-pattern, to make it easier to see whether it's used after deletion. In a release build, I'd be worried.

Comment: Looking through some [MSDN discussions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a51fe950-cd74-4133-8d84-1bc07b353bc2/msvc-2005-automatically-calling-memset?forum=Vsexpressvc) it looks like it may be part of MSVC's compiler optimizations. If you set "Optimization" to "Optimize Speed" in the project options, it should go away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In debug version of the Microsoft C/C++ Runtime library, `delete` sets the freed memory to `0xDD` using `memset`. That's why you see `memset` in the callstack. You won't see it in release version.
Likewise when memory is allocated through `new`, the newly allocated memory is set to `0xCD`.

You can see some of the details here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx

Comment: Is it also normal to access that memory after deletion and not have a crash of the app in debug mode?

Comment: @TM_ that's possible in release also. Accessing memory after deletion is undefined behaviour. Anything can happen including great things or bad stuff.

Comment: I have checked the value of destructed `bool` is `true (254)` and value of destructed `int` is `-17891602`

Answer (score 3):

May be you're working in debug mode. In that case it's common to fill freed areas to detect early if someone keeps reading a freed block.

Also when reusing the block later it's possible to detect if someone wrote to an area after deleting it

Comment: So after deleting it I can still use that object if I remember the address?

Comment: @TM_: NO.  Do not use an object after you delete it.  It is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @TM_: No. You cannot, but it's a common error to do that and this is the reason for which debug versions of the library fills the memory with special patterns to accelerate the detection of this kind of bug (for example if your `page_number` suddenly becomes 3735928559 the rest of the program hopefully will crash earlier).